# How to connect with Excel Sheet in SharePoint Online to an on premise Cube?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, ssas, sharepoint-online

I have an on premise SSAS Cube and an Excel Sheet which connect to this Cube and the user is able to filter and work with the data. Now the Excel Sheet should be placed in SharePoint Online and the user should be still able to connect to the on premise Cube through Excel Services for refreshing the data etc.

Is this possible and if yes, which options do i have?